How to block requests to Translator service based on number of characters in the source document?
I'm working on a project that utilizes Microsoft Azure's AI Translator service to translate documents in various formats. Specifically, I'm using the batch translation API.
The problem:
The Translator service pricing is based on number of characters in translated document. And the number of characters is knows only after the document was processed by the service.
I would like to control the the amount of characters processed by the service and maybe stop the execution if the character count is above a threshold.
Is there any solution out there in Azure's landscape that can help me? I would like to avoid creating a custom service to count characters , for various file types supported by AI Translator
So far, I read the services documentation and searched the internet...Alas, it seems people just write their own code to count teh characters.

Yes you have to count characters using your own code. There is no such kind of service from translator to calculate character count in doc.
